# SELECT best 50 results and GROUP BY id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with the results and details of a tournament and its players (participants) and I want to retrieve the sum for all the best 50 scores for all the players, in descending order. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT punctaj.id, ROUND(SUM(punctaj.punctaj_etapa)) AS puctaj_total, jucatori.nume 
FROM punctaj 
JOIN jucatori ON punctaj.id = jucatori.id 
WHERE sezon = 19 OR sezon = 20 OR sezon = 21 OR sezon = 22 OR sezon = 23 OR sezon = 24
GROUP BY punctaj.id 
ORDER BY puctaj_total DESC
```

but this returns the sum for all the results and I need to get the sum only for the best 50 scores. So I think I need a subquery to use a limit for the best 50 players in descending order or something like that. 
The table looks like this:

[image]

Please advise! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I want to retrieve the 50 best score sum for each player and for specific seasons (which I will add into the WHERE clause). The image I attached is for the `punctaj` table and I didn't add the image for the `jucatori` table because I thought it's not really helpful since it's containing some names with some IDs on which I am doing a JOIN to get the name for each player depending on his individual ID. So `jucatori` contains two columns: `id` and `nume`.
The results don't need to be grouped by season, I only need to get the sum for the best 50 results for the seasons I add on the WHERE clause.
If I add a `LIMIT 50`, I believe this should be added before the `SUM` is calculated, so I believe a subquery it's needed, but I don't have too much experience with MySQL.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 50` if you only want the 50 first?

Comment: It is not clear if you want the 50 best score sum for each player player or for all, and also if you want that for all seasons or for a number of seasons, and a group by per season. The image you have shown doesnt reflect the SQL you have shown, so that is even more disturbing. Edit your question and clarify

Comment: @ThomasG - I updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: ok this is quite hard to do in MySQL, but I might come with a solution later. The question is: are you on MySQL 8? If yes you can use the new window functions and that will be easier.

Comment: I believe this is the MySQL version I have: Server version: 5.6.39-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Comment: I can do this for a single person like this: 
`SELECT SUM(innerTable.punctaj_etapa) FROM (SELECT * FROM punctaj WHERE id = 1 AND (sezon = 19 OR sezon = 20 OR sezon = 21 OR sezon = 22 OR sezon = 23 OR sezon = 24) ORDER BY punctaj_etapa DESC LIMIT 50) AS innerTable`.
But I cannot do it for all the participants.